# ./configure of R doesn't see loaded readline environment module

Tags: r, build

I try to install R according to https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Installing-R-under-Unix_002dalikes-1, i.e.

```bash
wget https://cloud.r-project.org/src/base/R-latest.tar.gz
tar -xf R-latest.tar.gz
cd R-4.3.3
module load gcc
module load readline
./configure --prefix=$HOME/R --with-readline
```

But this fails with `readline` not being found, i.e.

```
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for sin in -lm... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for readline/history.h... no
checking for readline/readline.h... no
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for main in -lncurses... no
checking for main in -ltinfo... no
checking for main in -ltermcap... no
checking for main in -ltermlib... no
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
```

The readline module appends `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, `MANPATH`, `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I fail to understand how to tell the configure step where the `readlin` includes because

```
./configure --help
```

doesn't show an option to e.g. give the path to the `readline` base dir.

What am I missing here?